# Diff Between Different Tables Columns

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures, join, triggers

I have the following Join:

```
SELECT
    da.DataEstimada,
    ca.DataMoldagem,
    da.DataEnsaio,        
    da.IdadeRompimento,
    r.CompressaoConcretoId
FROM dadoscpconcreto da 
    INNER JOIN relacaodadoscpcompressaoconcreto r ON da.DadosCpConcretoId = r.DadosCpConcretoId
    INNER JOIN compressaoconcreto cc on r.CompressaoConcretoId = cc.CompressaoConcretoId
    INNER JOIN cpcaminhao ca ON da.CpCaminhaoId = ca.CpCaminhaoId
    INNER JOIN relacaoconcretocpcaminhao re ON ca.CpCaminhaoId = re.CpCaminhaoId
    INNER JOIN concreto c ON re.ConcretoId = c.ConcretoId    

WHERE r.CompressaoConcretoId = 244
```

Which returns me :

DataEstimada| DataMoldagem | DataEnsaio | IdadeRompimento   |

2014-10-31 |  2014-10-24  | 2014-10-31 |     null          |

2014-10-31 |  2014-10-24  | 2014-10-31 |     null          |

2014-11-21 |  2014-10-24  | 2014-11-21 |     null          |

2014-11-21 |  2014-10-24  | 2014-11-21 |     null          |

I would like to create a function , procedure or trigger that made the difference between the fields 'DataEnsaio' of dadoscpconcreto table and 'DataMoldagem' of cpcaminhao table and set the 'IdadeRompimento' field of dadoscpconcreto table.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to read MySQL documentacion about [DateDiff Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) as starting point.